# SharedPreferences values not retrieved from a service when called from another activity that created them

Tags: android

Good day, am having a quite baffling problem and its supposed to be pretty much straightforward. i have this 3 class:

```
1.A config activity that creates and saves sharedpreferences.

2.A service.

3.Another Activity B
```

From the Config Activity, i save in this manner:

```
prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREF_NAME, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

 boolean toggleCheck = toggleCelsius.isChecked();
 boolean currentLocation = mylocation.isChecked();
 boolean searchLocation = search.isChecked();
 int updateSet = update.getSelectedItemPosition();

 Editor editor = prefs.edit();
 editor.putString(CITY + appWidgetId, city);
 editor.putBoolean(GPS_LOCATION + appWidgetId, currentLocation);
 editor.putBoolean(SEARCH_LOCATION + appWidgetId, searchLocation);
 editor.putBoolean(CHECKED_CELSIUS + appWidgetId , toggleCheck);
 editor.putInt(REFRESH_UPDATE + appWidgetId, updateSet);
 editor.commit();
```

and i retrieve from the service onCreate() Method this way:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(myCastConfigure.MY_PREF_NAME, MODE_WORLD_READABLE); //have tried using getApplicationContext()
 city = prefs.getString(CITY + appWidgetId,"nothing");
 chk_celsius = prefs.getBoolean(CHECKED_CELSIUS + appWidgetId, true);
 updateRate = Configure.convertToMillis(prefs.getInt(REFRESH_UPDATE + appWidgetId, 1));
```

After i save the preferences, the service starts and i can retrieve the sharedPreferences Value from the service.But when i try to restart the service from the Activity B, i don't retrieve the sharedpreference value from the service anymore. instead i get the value "nothing". I have tried using getApplicationContext() from the service, but that doesn't seem to help too! can anybody please explain whats going on and give suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: I have the same issue, smells like bug... Everything is ok at the first try, but the second... returns false, but the value is true...

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving and reading the same key:

```
editor.putString(CITY, city);
prefs.getString(CITY + appWidgetId,"nothing");
```

You save CITY but read CITY + appWidgetId

Comment: oh no sorry.. its in my code, i save it the same way. i would edit it.

Comment: @manuelJ You should paste the same code you are actually using - odds are that there is something wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I have found the solution. The problem is, I think, that your service is running in a different process.

```
<service
            android:name="servicename"
            android:process=":my_process" > --> option1: delete this
        </service>
```

and sharedpreferences are not supported in different services... you can do 2 things. The first is, to run the service on the main thread, or set `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` when calling `getSharedPreferences()`.

Better late then never :)